# Speeding up complex functions on pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am filling up NaN values in one column of my dataframe using the followikng code:

```
for i in tqdm(range(nadf.shape[0])):
    a = nadf["primary"][i]
    nadf["count"][i] = np.ceil(d[a]*a)
```

This code replaces the NaN values in the "count" by multiplying the corresponding value of the "primary" in a dictionary d with the value of "primary". The nadf has 16 million rows. I understand that the execution will be slow, but is there a method to speed this up?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to reproduce as well as set a baseline for being _slow_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question and dataframe value in a right way, the problem can be solved the following way by using pandas internal functionality:

Please follow comments in code, feel free to ask questions.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math


def fill_nan(row, _d):
    """fill nan values in "count" column based on "primary" column value and dictionary _d"""

    if math.isnan(row["count"]):
        return np.ceil(_d[row["primary"]]) * row["primary"]
    return row["count"]  # else not nan


if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30}

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "primary": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2],
        "count": [10.1, 4, 5, np.nan, np.nan, 4, np.nan]
    })

    df["count"] = df.apply(lambda row: fill_nan(row, d), axis=1)  # changes nan here

    print(df)
```